# How to recreate the private key for the apple certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

I am missing the private key for one of my apple certificates and I am looking to recreate it or retrieve it somehow.

Is there any method on how to recreate a private Key for an apple certificate, without having to contact the original developer who created the certificate ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recreate the private key. It is gone forever if you cannot find a backup copy. You will need to create a new private key and then create a new certificate using that key.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try to get it from your own keychain (under keys) if it was created on your machine.